# Setter sets String value but Getter returns null or default String value

Tags: java, android, string, null, getter-setter

I want to get string value from **editText** so I use **TextWatcher** **onTextChanged** method to set String value on my **private String cName**. And it sets and gets right value.

```
@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add,parent,false);

    dNameText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.d_name);
    dNameText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            dCloud.setName(s.toString());
            Log.e(TAG,"name " + dCloud.getName());
        }

    });
```

here is my setter and getter **public class**

```
private String cName = "ggg";

public String getName(){return cName;}

public void setName(String name) {cName = name;}
```

but when I want to use getter in other method or some where else I always getting **private String cName** default value **"ggg"** or if I leave empty I'm getting null. Why **private String cName** not staying on setted value and how I can fix it?

Comment: Use a database to store you can access it anywhere

Comment: or I can use SQLite for offline apps as well?

Comment: Data you store in variables is not persistent across app restarts - use a database or `SharedPreferences` for that.

Answer (score 0):

The value of cName won't change unless your TextView's text is changed from the UI.

I suggest that, before you use cName anywhere in your code, you test it for its default values (or simply null):

If cName equals its default value then the user haven't changed the text field yet. Else, then the text field has changed and you get the new value by calling getName().

Comment: I guess its always good practice to check for null value.But in this case I tested it on phone and when I typing something in EditText field it returns right value and when I press save button it calls getName() method and app crashes because it returns null or it saves with default value "ggg".